# Coldfusion Server Side Radio Validation

Tags: validation, coldfusion

I'm trying to validate that a radio button has been selected via server side in ColdFusion. The text input errors out if empty, however, the radio button group does not trigger an error if none are selected. I cannot seem to find any documentation on this.

```
  <cfform name="mobile_device_request" id="form" action="">
      Text Box:
      <cfinput type="Text" name="subscriber" message="Please enter in a subscriber" required="yes" validateat="onserver">

      Subscriber:
      <cfinput type="Radio" name="service_provider" value="AT&amp;T" required="yes" validateat="onserver"><span class="label">AT&amp;T</span>
      <cfinput type="Radio" name="service_provider" value="Sprint" required="yes" validateat="onserver"><span class="label">Sprint</span>
      <cfinput type="Radio" name="service_provider" value="Verizon" required="yes" validateat="onserver"><span class="label">Verizon</span>
```

Comment: Check if form.service_provider exists and please stop using cfform and cfinput

Comment: <cfif NOT isDefined('service_provider')> Error </cfif> *HTML5 covers most validation requirements provided by cfform

Comment: @Wes No. Always scope your variables. This is not good advice. HTML5 also isn't server side validation, it's client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

To answer your question, while I have never used that feature, I would say it is a bug.

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f51.html) `onServer` validation works by automatically appending hidden form fields with a special naming convention. The CF server then inspects all requests for [certain patterns in form field names](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a7b.html), such as ones ending in `_required` or `_cfformrequired`, and if found performs validation on the related field.

If you view the source of your cfform, notice CF has added several hidden fields:

```
<input type='hidden' name='subscriber_CFFORMREQUIRED' value='Please enter in a subscriber'>
<input type='hidden' name='service_provider_CFFORMREQUIRED' value='Error in service_provider text.'>
<input type='hidden' name='service_provider_CFFORMREQUIRED' value='Error in service_provider text.'>
<input type='hidden' name='service_provider_CFFORMREQUIRED' value='Error in service_provider text.'>
```

Those *should* trigger CF's server side validation for both fields. However, as you discovered it only works with the text field, not the radio buttons. Though curiously, it works just fine if you *manually* add a hidden field ending in `_required`:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="service_provider_required" 
         value='You forgot to select a service_provider'>
```

**Answer:**

Again, I think the behavior you are seeing may be a bug. Frankly, one of many with `cfform`. Personally, I would recommend ditching `cfform/cfinput`. Use plain html inputs and write your own validation instead. Since it is a radio button, the field will only be defined if one of the buttons was checked. So you can either test for the existence of the field:

```
    <cfif NOT structKeyExists(FORM, "service_provider")>
        no service_provider selected. do something
    </cfif>
```

... OR assign a default, and test for that value:

```
    <!--- default to empty string --->
    <cfparam name="FORM.service_provider" default="">
    <cfif NOT len(FORM.service_provider)>
        no service_provider selected. do something
    </cfif>
```

Comment: The problem with `_required` is they cause a hard error on the response page.

Comment: If by "hard error", you mean CF displays a server side error page - that is exactly what should happen. Also, just to clarify, my recommendation is to *not* use `cfinput` or `_required`. Instead use plain input fields and write your own validation, like in the example above.